# Can you access environment variables in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, rake-task

If I set up some environment variables in an `application.yml` file is there a way to access them inside a rake task? Doing `env['VARIABLE_NAME']` doesn't work and neither does `Rails.env['VARIABLE_NAME']`

My rake task:

```
task :create_new_assignment => [:environment] do
   puts env['VARIABLE_NAME'] # => fails.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this, it works with `ENV`:

```
task :temp => :environment do
  puts ENV['i']
end

% rake temp i=5
5
```